# Can't serve assets folder with lite-server

Tags: html, browser-sync, lite-server

I'm trying to serve an Angular project using lite-server. The server responds with a 404 whenever a file in assets folder is requested. I have created a 
bs-config.json and setting the routes option didn't work.

Here is my directory structure

```
node_modules/
src/
..app/
....index.html
..assets/
....img/
..config/
....bs-config.json
```

bs-config.json

```
{
  "port": 8000,
  "files": ["../src/**/*.{html,htm,css,js}"],
  "server": { 
    "baseDir": ["./src/app", "./"],
    "routes": {
      "/assets": "../assets"
    }
  }
}
```

How I try to load the files. (index.html)

```
<img src="assets/img/image.png">
```

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem but needed a resource at an absolute path not a relative one.

I needed something like `<img src="/assets/img/image.png">` and sovled it with a bs-config.json like

```
{
  "port": 8000,
  "files": ["../src/**/*.{html,htm,css,js}"],
  "server": { 
    "baseDir": ["./src/app", "./"
                "./src"               ///<----------Added this item
               ],    
  }
}
```

But I tried this with a relative URL and it didn't work.

I could see the URL requested by the browser in the lite-server log output so maybe you can check that and work from there?